# How to use redirect in codeigniter controller class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can any one tel me how to use redirect in controller class.

I am wrote below code:

**Controller:-**

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function result()
    {
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->index();
        redirect('/success', 'location');
    }   
}
```

**view:-**

success.php

```
<?php
   echo "Success page";
?>
```

It shows error message 404 Page Not Found.
I have load all required helper classes in autoload class.

Comment: if success is a controller it should be `success` and not `/success`. if success is a method of any controller then it should be `controller/success`

Comment: success is a view,its not a controller method.

Comment: you can't redirect directly to view. Have to redirect controller method which contain the view you want to show. Please check my answer for detail.

Comment: So redirect is only used for controllers right?we can not use for redirect views.

Comment: no you can not redirect to a view. redirect to a method which calls that view. @User

Comment: How can we pass a controller variable values to views.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter , redirect method takes 3 parameters.

```
redirect('/controller_name/method_name', 'location', 301);
```

First parameter is the uri path which you want to redirect. The second parameter is optional and takes "location" method (default) or the "refresh" method. The third optional parameter is status code. You can check detail on [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

**Edit**

```
function success () {
    $data["message"] = "Success";
    $this->load->view("success", $data);
}
```

views/success.php

```
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

You have to pass data in array because codeigniter use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) method to pass value in view so that you can use arrary key as variable.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to redirect is

Example:

```
public function index() {


redirect('controller_name'); 
// you may need to set controller name in routes do not need location

redirect('folder/controller_name'); 
// you may need to set controller name in routes do not need location

}
```

Comment: your answer is useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having these three files

`routes.php` where you can set your routes as like

```
$route['success'] = 'your_controller_name/your_method_name';
```

E.g.

```
$route['success'] = 'my_controller/success';
```

then within `your_controller.php`, there you have a method as

```
function success() {
  $data['msg'] = "Success";
  $this->load->view('success',$data);
}
```

and within your `success.php`

```
<?php echo "<h3>".$msg."<h3>";?>
```